# How to split list in pattern matching?

Tags: scala, list, pattern-matching

I have the following list:

```
val lst: List[Char] = //...
```

I would like to use it in pattern matching as follows:

```
lst match {
    case firstPart :: '|' :: theRestOfTheList =>
        //do something with them
}
```

The problem is `firstPart` is treated as a single character. But I want it to be the part of the list before the first `'|'`.

Is it possible to do so in a concise way in Scala?

Comment: Maybe `"hello|world".split("\\|", 2) match { case Array(start, tail) => start + tail }` ?

Comment: @XavierGuihot Actually can be a sulution!  Is that the most concise one? I suspect there could be something else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using custom extractor.

## Scala REPL

```
scala> val str: List[Char] = "foo|bar".toList
str: List[Char] = List(f, o, o, |, b, a, r)

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

 object SuperSplit {
    def unapply(list: List[Char]): Option[(List[Char], List[Char])] = {
      val (a, b) = list.splitAt(list.indexOf('|'))
      Some((a, b.tail))
    }
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object SuperSplit

scala> str match { case SuperSplit(a, b) => println(s"$a  $b")}
List(f, o, o)  List(b, a, r)
```

> Warning: Take care of corner cases where list is empty and others

Special syntax

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object `|` {
    def unapply(list: List[Char]): Option[(List[Char], List[Char])] = {
      val (a, b) = list.splitAt(list.indexOf('|'))
      Some((a, b.tail))
    }
  }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object $bar

scala> str match { case `|`(a, b) => println(s"$a  $b")}
List(f, o, o)  List(b, a, r)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's yet another way to do this if you're ok with turning the list of chars in a string and then matching it with a regex - I assumed you had the original list of chars from a string. Anyway here's the solution:

```
val pattern = """(.*)\|(.*)""".r
lst.mkString match {
  case pattern(left, right) => // do something with left & right strings
  case _                    => // do something else
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [span](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#span(p:A=>Boolean):(List[A],List[A])) *almost* is what you want, which splits the list into the longest prefix satisfying some predicate and the rest of the list :

```
val (firstPart, secondPart) = lst.span(_ != '|')
```

The caveat is that `secondPart` will have `|` as the first element, so your "real" second part would be `secondPart.tail`.

Comment: Note also that if there's no `|` present, `secondPart` is empty, so `secondPart.tail` will fail.